Use a NEW SESSION in JavaScript Fetch API
I am creating a web tool used on a kiosk that where 2 persons can insert their smart card. The tool will interact with our SmartCard-authenticated web app. The widget should prompt for user1's SmartCard and run fetch 1, then it should prompt for user2's SmartCard and run fetch 2.
If I use "credentials:include" in the fetch, it correctly authenticates with user1's Smart Card, but then both fetches use user 1's credentials. How can I initiate a second session/clear the LTPA Token/use a different session for each fetch? (Our web page, during SmartCard authentication uses 'Set-Cookie' and then carries auth in a cookie labeled 'LTPA2 Token').
Thanks in advance!

This sounds like something that should be solved on the backend. If the cookies are HttpOnly, you won't be able to manipulate them on the client

The cookies are HttpOnly. We don't have control of the back end code, but they allow the addition of 'custom widgets' that run JavaScripts on the dashboard, which is where our tool is running from. We need a button that allows a second user to POST something using their credentials to the server. Talking about it makes it sound like a security risk, but in reality it is a valid use case.

If you let the browser manage credentials, only 1 "session" / "user" is active at a given time, unless you:

Use a different cookie name for each user
Manage the requests and session/authentication tokens yourself by manually setting headers.
Use different orgins / domains per user.


"Use different orgins / domains per user"... or even paths

It would be fine to "logout" one user and then "login" another by manually setting cookies. But I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have looked at using a new Request, then deleting the headers, but 'Request.Headers.delete("Cookie") is ignored. In fact "Request.headers" is empty in the debugger, but then the cookie is sent anyway when viewing the Network tab in dev tools.

@Dave honestly you are probably better off not using cookies for this use-case anyway and using code-managed Authorization headers instead. Cookies feels like a bad solution for your unique problem.

@Dave anyway, that is a follow-up question and I think I've answered your main question so consider accepting it

I think Bullet 1 and 2 won't work, but what do you mean in Bullet 3?
Bullet 1: I do not have control of the server code where the fetch is headed.
Bullet 2: The server does standard auth with the Set-Cookie header establishing a cookie for the session. Since Set-Cookie is a protected header that JavaScript won't read, I can't manually manage headers.
I would love just initiating a second session that is disconnected from the main session if that were possible, and letting Fetch handle auth automatically.

If you don't control the target server, another idea is to deploy a small proxy service that manages auth.
